# Get Databindings from two different locations

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

i want to display a "Set Image" before the "Set Name" in a ComboBox, but the API that i'm using to fetch the data does not give me a URL to get the image from so i have to create that on my own. it does however provide the gatherercode which is all i need to get the correct image like this:

```
Public string SetImageUrl = String.Format("http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?type=symbol&set={0}&size={1}&rarity={2}", sets.gatherercode, setImageSize, setImageRarity)
```

but how can i bind SetImageUrl to image source if it's in MainPage.xaml.cs, when i have set the itemsource to MagicSets and the DataType to a different namespace (appName.Api instead of appName). or how can i create my own:

```
[DataMember(Name = "setImageUrl")]
public string setImageUrl{ get; set; }
```

That takes all the values as the above string.

The result of the code that i now have i that i get a combobox that have an item for each set in sets that has a textblox that displays set.name

XAML Code

```
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ComboBox Name="SetComboBox" ItemsSource="{x:Bind MagicSets}">
                <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:Set">
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image source="{Binding imageUrl}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind name}"/>
                        </Stackpanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ComboBox>
        </StackPanel>
```

SetDataWrapper Code

```
    [DataContract]
public class Set
{
    [DataMember(Name = "code")]
    public string code { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "type")]
    public string type { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "border")]
    public string border { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "mkm_id")]
    public int mkm_id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "booster")]
    public IList<object> booster { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "mkm_name")]
    public string mkm_name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "releaseDate")]
    public string releaseDate { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "gathererCode")]
    public string gathererCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "magicCardsInfoCode")]
    public string magicCardsInfoCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "block")]
    public string block { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "oldCode")]
    public string oldCode { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "onlineOnly")]
    public bool? onlineOnly { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class SetDataWrapper
{
    [DataMember(Name = "sets")]
    public IList<Set> sets { get; set; }
}
```

}

Main Page Code

```
        public ObservableCollection<Card> MagicCards { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Set> MagicSets { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        MagicCards = new ObservableCollection<Card>();
        MagicSets = new ObservableCollection<Set>(); 
    }
    private async void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ProgressRingToggle(true);
        await MagicFacade.PopulateMagicCardsAsync(MagicCards);
        await MagicFacade.PopulateMagicSetsAsync(MagicSets);
        ProgressRingToggle(false);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

> how can i create my own:[DataMember(Name = "setImageUrl")]
>   public string setImageUrl{ get; set; }That takes all the values as the above string.

You can add constructor to your `Set` Class. And in constructor to set the `setImageUrl` parameter as follows:

```
[DataContract]
public class Set
{
    public Set(string ImageSize, string setImageRarity)
    {
        setImageUrl = String.Format("http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?type=symbol&set={0}&size={1}&rarity={2}", gathererCode, ImageSize, setImageRarity);
    }
    [DataMember(Name = "setImageUrl")]
    public string setImageUrl { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "code")]
    public string code { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string name { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "type")]
    ...
```

Set the `ImageSize` and `setImageRarity` when you instantiate the class like follows:

```
MagicSets = new ObservableCollection<Set>() {
    new Set("medium","Rarity1"){name="suntest1",gathererCode="code"},
    new Set("medium","Rarity2"){name="suntest2",gathererCode="code"}
};
```

After then, you can bind the `setImageUrl` same as the `name`.

```
<ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Set">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Image Source="{x:Bind setImageUrl}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind name}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```